# Search a text file for two strings and display how many strings are in between

Tags: java, arrays, performance, binary-search

How can I use Binary search in Java to find how many strings lie between the two strings given by the user? I have a large text file to search through.
I was thinking ((word position 2 - word position 1)-1) would give the position from an array but I am not quite sure how to put it into code. I got stuck after checking the file for the words.

```
String[] allWords = new String[400000];
        int wordCount = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\text.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) {
    String word = input.next();
    allWords[wordCount] = word;
    wordCount++;

    System.out.println(wordCount); 
}

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\text.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String in = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc2.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a string:");
    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str2 = sc3.nextLine();

    if (str.contains(str)) {
    System.out.println("yes");
}
    if (str.contains(str2)) {
    System.out.println("yes");

    }
```

Comment: I don't quite see the relevance of binary search for this. Binary search is all about not having to search the whole 'tree', (an array of elements in some order is a bit like having elements in a tree).  but if you want to know how many things are in between then you'd have to check all elements in between..  I guess maybe binary search for the element then remove/rewrite it to something else. Then binary search again e.t.c.  though I don't know really.

Comment: Why binary search? Read the file line by line. See if the line equals either string. If the line equals one of the strings start counting until the other string is found.

Comment: So if I read it line by line like it does in my code how do I start the counting?  I am somewhat new to programming so I am not sure of how to do things like taking input from a user and put it in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your math is correct.  As you have surmised, subtract one from the difference of the positions.  If you have any issues with the code, post your attempt to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I posted my code so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this pseudocode.

```
int start
int end
a = startingString
b = startingString

String[] lines  = StringFromFile.split("\n");

for(x in lines)
    if(x=a)
        start = position of x
for(x in lines)
    if(x=b)
        end = position of x
String[] newLines = Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, start,end)
return newLines.length
```

Comment: Thank you! This simplifies things down! So now I have the input for the user to store the two words and also the location. I believe I am struggling with the for and if statements.

Comment: No problem, my guy